# Judge whether the post order of a binary search tree is valid

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, postorder

Here is my code, there are three test cases, but I only passed two of them. And I don't figure out what's wrong with code. Please help me!

```
#include <cstdio>

int isValid(int a[], int low, int high) {
    if (low >= high)
        return 1;

    int root = a[high];
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] < root && i < high)
        i++;
    // i == low, the left child is null
    // i == high, the right child is null
    if (a[i - 1] < root && root < a[high - 1] 
        || i == low && root < a[high - 1] || a[i - 1] < root && i == high) {
        return isValid(a, low, i - 1) && isValid(a, i, high - 1);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    while (scanf("%d", &n) != EOF) {
        int a[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);

        if (isValid(a, 0, n - 1)) {
            printf("Yes\n");
        } else {
            printf("No\n");     
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
7

5 7 6 9 11 10 8

4

7 4 6 5
```

Sample output:

```
Yes

No
```

Comment: Which of those two cases does it fail? What is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: the problem is the one of online judge. I can't get the test data.

Comment: You don't seem to consider edge cases. For instance, when there is only one element in the array, you try to read `a[-1]`. Come up with your own test cases, and if one of them gives you trouble, show it to us; until then, I vote to close.

Comment: well, if there is only one element in the array, when invoke the isValid, the low is 0, the high is 0 (n=1, so n -1 =0), then low == high, it will return true.

Comment: You're right, I missed the `i++`. Well, that's one edge case taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder could guarantee the nondecreasing order for BST, but poster-order can't. And you can't deduce the original binary tree from the poster-order sequence. Take an instance, 5 7 6 could be valid full BST also could be invalid BST.

Comment: only if match the postorder of the certain valid BST, that will be correct!

Comment: So the output of 5 6 7 is Yes

Comment: How about the follow binary tree? 6 is the root and has one left-child 7 who only has one left child 5. It post-order sequence is 5 7 6

Comment: But if 6 is root and has one left-child 5, one right-child 7, it could be correct! and the post-order is also 5 7 6.